# How to use map for distributed actions?

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to perform distributed actions inside `RDD.map`?

I explain :

- I read a JSON and I parallelize it through Spark
- I perform a map operation and inside its "call" method, I execute a CURL
- I get the result of the CURL and I process the RDD according the result

I know this works but I was wondering if the CURL will be performed by the driver or by an executor?

Comment: by executor of course. what ever calculation is done in map function is in executor

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That's not always true, but for `Dataset.map` it is. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an edit the question became and the answer is again yes.

> Is it possible to perform distributed actions inside `RDD.map`?

I also wrote in a comment that *"you should stay away from RDD API unless Spark SQL's Dataset API won't meet your requirements."*

So the following item from the question:

> I read a JSON and I parallelize it through Spark

should really be as follows:

> I read a JSON in Spark SQL

I think that my explanation still holds (regardless of the API, Spark SQL's Dataset vs Spark Core's RDD).

---

> Is it possible to perform distributed actions inside a Map ?

Inside a [Dataset.map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) operator? It is already a distributed computation (as most structured queries in Spark SQL that are "described" using Dataset API) and `map` will just carry on.

> I know this works but I was wondering if the CURL will be performed by the driver or by an executor ?

For `map` it will be on a Spark executor.

Be careful though as it does not have to be this way if you offered your own `map` operator (via implicit conversions).

Where a query is executed depends on the implementation of a logical operator in use as some are executed on the driver - see [Command](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/Command.scala#L27) and [RunnableCommand](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/commands.scala#L40) logical operators and [ExecutedCommandExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/commands.scala#L55) physical operator.

Spark SQL comes with many optimizations that do change how queries work (as compared to Spark Core's RDDs). That's one of the many reasons to stick to Spark SQL (and avoid Spark Core's RDD API as long as possible).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacek for your explanations and your time, it helps a lot. You said to stay away from RDD API, could you tell me why ? I use Dataframes with SparkSQL to process datas and it is very handy. But in this case I use Spark to distribute batch of actions (Is it relevant ? I don't know yet) like "curling" an url, fetch its result, performing others actions.

Comment: Do everything in Spark SQL unless you know that RDD API could be more efficient. Curling an URL should also be possible with Dataset API with `foreach` or alike.